# Why is a array with the size power of 2 slower? Why do i gain with -rdynamic performance?

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, caching, optimization

I have a simple array operation in a for loop, which is done for different sizes (from 16 to really big) of the array, which contains doubles. I do these several times:

```
for(int i = 1; i < n-1; i++){
    target[i] = (source[i-1]+source[i]+source[i+1])*0.5;
}
```

I compiled it with "-O3 -march=native" and measured the speed.  I then, for reasons not relevant here, tried adding "-rdynamic", for a significant speedup, as you can see in the plot.  "cmake" in the legend refers to the "-rdynamic" addition.  This only works on a  i7-4790 CPU. I couldn't reproduce it on a AMD Phenom II X6 1045T at all.

I certainly don't understand why -rdynamic would produce a speed-up that big. (GLOPS = #updates of the array cells per second in billions). Why do i gain a speed up? Why not on the AMD CPU?

Notice that these measurements are the mean value of ten measurements for both cases each.

And another interesting observation is that at least in the beginning, as the array fits in the L1 cache, i have these drops of performance. Interesting about it is, that those happens as the size of my array is power of 2. I guess this has something to do with the L2 cache, but i absolutely don't know what and why. Maybe some cache conflicts, or alignment?

[image]

EDIT:
I have now properly plotted just with:
    g++ -O3 -march=native programm.cpp -rdynamic
The curve labelled "cmake" is the same as adding "-rdynamic".

EDIT 2:
Removed cmake narrative from the question entirely.[Peter]

Comment: It would be a great first step to abstract cmake out of this entirely. It's just a build system. You've already identified that it's adding flags to your GCC invocation, so why not focus on that?

Comment: But i did that. And i am focusing that: "So apparently, it uses just -rdynamic more. I reproduced the same speedup with a per-hand compilation including the -rdynamic." I just compiled it with g++ -O3 -march=nativ program.cpp -rdynamic. So cmake was not directly there.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why the rdynamic would result in a speedup. But regarding your second question, check Agner Fog's guide "Optimizing software in C++" http://www.agner.org/optimize/optimizing_cpp.pdf. Have a look at section 9.2 where he talks about critical stride. Might be applicable in this situation.